# Is there a way to change the order of these summation terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation

$$\sum_{K=2}^{N}\sum_{L=1}^{\lfloor\frac{K}{2}\rfloor-1}$$

I want to have the $L$ summation on the outside and the $K$ summation on the inside somehow. Can this be done?

Comment: Are these $L$ and $K$ finite sum terms?  What happens when you expand the sum fully?  Can you regroup the terms?

Comment: I tried that and couldn't find any clean way to do it

Comment: For any fixed value of $L$, $K$ travels from $2L$ to $N$, So the inner sum is $\sum_{K=2L}^N$.

Comment: I tried that already; it led me to make the outer sum L=1 to floor(N/2) which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=2}^Na_k\sum_{j=1}^{[\frac{k}{2}]-1}b_j=a_4(b_1)+a_5(b_1)+a_6(b_1+b_2)+a_7(b_1+b_2)+a_8(b_1+b_2+b_3)...$$
$$=b_1(a_4+a_5+a_6...a_N)+b_2(a_6+a_7+a_8+...a_N)+b_3(a_8+a_9+a_{10}...+a_N)...$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{N}{2}]-1}b_k\sum_{j=2(k+1)}^{N}a_j$$

So that we get,

$$\sum_{k=2}^Na_k\sum_{j=1}^{[\frac{k}{2}]-1}b_j=\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{N}{2}]-1}b_k\sum_{j=2(k+1)}^{N}a_j$$

Comment: This is not correct

Comment: Why is this not correct?

Comment: Try sample N=10, then try adding up +1 for each iteration of the inner loop. Correct one gives you 16, the rewrite gives 25

Comment: You get 16 with the new one? k=1 to 5. so j=2 to 10, 4 to 10, 6 to 10, 8 to 10, 10 to 10. That's 9+7+5+3+1=25

Comment: It looks like the mistake is on my end. My inner bound is not floor(K/2) but rather floor(K/2)-1

Comment: With the updated inner sum bound doesn't that change things because now it's not a clean cutoff between the regroupings

Comment: That piece just isn't included in anything, i.e. equal to 0

Comment: No it's still wrong; the inner sum is only "undefined" for that one particular spot, but the rest are OK since the sum is defined

Comment: @user2175923 No everything I wrote is correct, I am really getting tired of this.

Comment: It's not though because now neither bound ever starts off at 1 from what I can tell, correct

Comment: @user2175923 Ok, my bad I see now. Just fixed it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, sorry for the miscommunication earlier